# Using Rumps in Python and OS X Without Creating a Class

Tags: python, macos

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8544853/701410) that explains how to use rumps on OS X to create a system menu in Python.  It's basically taken from the [rumps documentation](http://rumps.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#simple-subclass-structure) and I've seen it used almost any place rumps is demonstrated.

I realize that if I use rumps, I'll have to use it as an object, but is it possible to just create the appropriate rumps object in my code without creating an extra class of my own to use it?

If not, is there a reason rumps must be used within another object and can't be used without creating what amounts to a wrapper class?

Are there any examples (or can anyone provide an example) of how to use rumps to create a system menu, including having calls to a function in a program, without using any OOP other than what's required directly by rumps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps/blob/master/examples/example_simple.py) what you're looking for?

You can create an instance of `rumps.App` directly, then decorate your non-member functions as `@rumps.click()` to get them to run. Basically:

```
@rumps.clicked("About")
def about(sender):
    rumps.alert("This is a cool app!")

@rumps.clicked("Preferences")
def about(sender):
    rumps.alert("This is a cool app's settings!")

app = rumps.App("My Toolbar App", title='World, Hello')
app.menu = [
    rumps.MenuItem('About', icon='pony.jpg', dimensions=(18, 18)), 
    'Preferences',
]
app.run()
```

Comment: Did you mean to make the 2nd function name "preferences" instead of "about?"

Comment: yeah, sorry, I wrote that in a hurry. I don't think it matters what you call it, as long as it's tagged.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I just wanted to verify it to make sure I understood it correctly.  Thanks.