# Creating Sub Menu for Menu item using Rumps python on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, appkit, rumps

I got this example code form this question [Using Rumps in Python and OS X Without Creating a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162748/using-rumps-in-python-and-os-x-without-creating-a-class)

```
@rumps.clicked("About")
def about(sender):
    rumps.alert("This is a cool app!")

@rumps.clicked("Preferences")
def about(sender):
    rumps.alert("This is a cool app's settings!")

app = rumps.App("My Toolbar App", title='World, Hello')
app.menu = [
    rumps.MenuItem('About', icon='pony.jpg', dimensions=(18, 18)), 
    'Preferences',
]
app.run()
```

How do I create a submenu for About menuitem with values like, "About Me", "About the Project" etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple to add a submenus to `rumps` — all that is required is to enclose the parent menu and children items in square brackets `[]`:

```
app.menu = [
    [rumps.MenuItem("About", icon='pony.jpg', dimensions=(18, 18)), 
    [rumps.MenuItem("About Me"), rumps.MenuItem("About Project"), 
    rumps.MenuItem("etc...")]], 
    None, 
    rumps.MenuItem('Preferences')
]
```

If you wanted to add another submenu for `etc...` for example you would do:

```
app.menu = [
    [rumps.MenuItem("About", 'icon='pony.jpg', dimensions=(18, 18)), 
    [rumps.MenuItem("About Me"), rumps.MenuItem("About Project"), 
    [rumps.MenuItem("etc..."), 
    [rumps.MenuItem("more!")]]]], 
    None, 
    rumps.MenuItem('Preferences')
]
```

Submenu items can also use `JSON` like syntax, which might be easier to manage if you have lots of children in your submenus:

```
app.menu = [
    rumps.MenuItem('About', icon='pony.png', dimensions=(18, 18)), 
    'Preferences',
    None,  # separator
    {'SubMenu':
        {"Child Menu One": ["Item 1", "Item 2"],
         "Child Menu Two": ["Item 1", rumps.MenuItem("Item 2")]}},
    None
]
```

> *`None` acts as a separator and is entirely optional.

You can find some [more examples here](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps/tree/ae11371bddcafbabc5f62d1eadddf83bfbd653dc/examples).