# Kivy desktop toolbar

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, kivy

Does anyone know how to change the Toolbar in Kivy for desktop applications? I know how to do this in Tkinter, using Menus but I do not know how to do this in Kivy. When I was searching for this, the only thing I could find was ActionBar, which doesn't seem to change the toolbar. I am trying to make a dropdown in the toolbar with checkboxes. I have attached a screenshot of what I am talking about when I say "Toolbar". Please provide example code of making the toolbar too.
[image: Toolbar Picture]

Comment: Do you need it specific for macos?

Comment: I do not need it specific for MacOS but my target platform is MacOS so it has to work on MacOS.

Comment: I know how to do it on macOS with the help of [*PyObjC*](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/) library, [Here is an answer that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28455289/10364425). Also, I think if you use pyqt5 you can implement menubar with kivy application though I never tried i just read somewhere.

Comment: Are there any simple examples? I couldn't find anything on how actually to do it, only recommendations for the PyObjC library